# Ищу аналог password-verify() из php на языке C++

Tags: c++-cli

Добрый день. В php есть очень классная вещь для хеширования и проверки паролей. В частности функции password_hash() и password_verify().
Мне необходима такая же вещь для CLI C++. 
Знаю для C# есть CryptSharp, где это реализовано. Но библиотеки от C# не подойдут для С++.
Есть ли аналоги для С++?

Comment: Реализовать собственную функцию на основе примитивов из openSSL - не вариант?

Comment: Если есть для C#, то использовать в C++/CLI не должно быть проблемой, это же все тот же .Net.